# Webpage Requires User Interaction to Load in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, google-chrome, safari

I have a web application that behaves strangely in Safari compared to other browsers like Chrome and Firefox. Specifically, certain pages in my web app only load and function correctly in Safari when I manually trigger a user interaction, such as a click or keyboard event. Without this interaction, the page remains in a loading state.

Here are some key details about the issue:

The problem is isolated to Safari; other browsers work as expected.
There are no apparent errors or warnings in the Safari Developer Tools' console or network tab.
The issue affects only specific pages within my web app, while others work fine without user interaction.
The web app relies on Angular, and some pages may include AJAX or http requests, event listeners, and DOM manipulations.
I have thoroughly reviewed the Typescript/JavaScript code and the event handling logic but haven't been able to identify any clear reasons for this behavior.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or debugging strategies to help me resolve this issue and ensure consistent functionality across all browsers, including Safari.

Checked the Safari Developer Tools' console and network tab for errors or warnings, but found none related to the issue.
Reviewed the JavaScript code for the affected pages, including event handlers, AJAX requests, and DOM manipulations, to ensure they were correctly implemented.
Tested the web app in different versions of Safari, as well as in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox), where it worked as expected.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do, and most things _don't_ require user interaction except say, playing a video with audio. I have not encountered this, and since you provide no code at all, there is no way for us to see why this is happening in your specific case, so please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that blocks in Safari.

Comment: If you are referring to playing video for example, there is a way you can enable autostart in developer mode, just for your sake. However, you can't force it for the production mode.

Comment: I dont know which part of code is creating an issue thats why I have not provided the code, any help would be appreciated

Comment: No here user interaction means a click, when I click anywhere on the page it loads as expected.